# Docx4j writes XML as default in a Word document

Tags: java, xml, ms-word, hashmap, docx4j

I'm trying to write simple text (String) to a Word document by replacing variables in a Word template with the following code:

```
MainDocumentPart documentPart = template.getMainDocumentPart();
        try {
            documentPart.variableReplace(replaceHashMap);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Docx4JException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And in my Main class I've something like this:

```
for( StringWriter sw : wsdlHelper.getWSDLTemplateRequest() )
        {
            document.addHashMapping("API REQUEST", sw.toString().replace("<", "#1#").replace(">", "#2#"));
        }
```

I'm replacing in the String "<" with "#1#" and ">" with "#2#" for test purposes and it works flawlessly.

But I if I remove these replacements Docx4j interprets the String as a XML, sometimes even notifies of unclosed tags and the output document in the place of the chosen variable (API REQUEST) is empty!

I just need it to interpret as a String and write to the Word document as plain text "as is".
I'm trying to write the request template of a Webservice as simple text, is there also a way to pretty print it directly in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your document should contain variables of the form ${VAR}.

The document is marshalled to a string (containing XML).

Sub-strings of the form ${VAR} are then replaced with whatever you have specified.

Typically that would be simple text, not XML.  If you want an angle bracket '<' to appear in your output, use &lt;

The result is then unmarshalled.  Unexpected content is dropped.

Comment: When I replace the angle brackets with "$lt" and "&gt" I get the following error. Am I missing something? Thanks for the help.

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 4769; The reference to entity "lts11:Envelope" must end with the ';' delimiter.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
 at ....
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

Comment: This code I'm using:
System.out.println("Creating a template request for each port type: " + filename);
        for( StringWriter sw : wsdlHelper.getWSDLTemplateRequest() )
        {
            addHashMapping("API REQUEST", sw.toString().replace("<", "#1#").replace(">", "#2#"));
        }

Comment: An entity reference (eg &lt; ) ends with a semi colon; don't omit it.   That's why the exception says "must end with the ';' delimiter"

Comment: Thanks for the help @JasonPlutext that solved my problem! Marking as the answer.